# Why I get 405 method not allowed while I'm calling the defined method?

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel framework. Here is my route:

```
routes/api.php

Route::prefix('panel/v1')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Panel\V1')->group(function () {
    Route::post('live/main', 'LiveController@homeLive');
```

As you can see, it's defined as `POST`. But I get the following error:

[image]

Why it complains about the `GET` method, while I don't neither called nor defined the `GET` method?

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan route:list` to see if it is there

Comment: in addition to @francisco's comment, try setting the prefix as the `group()s` part like `group(['prefix' => 'yourprefix'])`

Comment: Thanks @francisco, but your second command returns error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qljRG.png

Comment: did you import  the controller? add `use App\Http...\ForumController` to the top of the `api.php`

Comment: @MartinAJ what's you laravel version btw?

Comment: @francisco Laravel Framework 9.52.4

Comment: @MartinAJ the `'LiveController@homeLive'` is [old fashion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-default-route-files). Change for use:

```use App\Http\Controllers\LiveController;
 
Route::post('/live/main', [LiveController::class, 'homeLive']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error clearly sais GET. So the post is converted in GET by htaccess rewrite or ngnx or apache. Example http to https or www to non www or non www to www.

Comment: Yeah, I had a http to https 301 redirect that was the root cause of the issuer